# Code signing error: Doesn't match key pair in default keychain

Tags: iphone, xcode, codesign

*****Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer: XXXXXXXXXX' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain**.***

I am a member in developer profile, I have the provisioning profile installed, what must be the problem here?

**Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer: XXXXXXXXXXXX' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain**

What am I supposed to do? I already searched for a solution but still didn't find any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error suggests that there is a problem with either your certificate or your private key.

If you open Keychain Access (in Applications/Utilities), do you see  'iPhone Developer: XXXXXXXXXX' in your certificates?  If not, you need to download it from the Program Portal.

When you created the certificate 'iPhone Developer: XXXXXXXXXX', did you generate a certificate signing request *on the same computer* that you are now using to compile?  If not, the private key that goes with your certificate may not be installed on the computer; whoever generated the signing request will need to send it to you, and you will need to add it to your keychain.

Comment: i need the .p12 and .cert certificate that matches with the provisioning profile...    again one more thing is it necessary to change bundle identity with the identity in provisioning profile...
thanx for help i will try it out thatx for replying in such a short time..

Comment: For distribution, you do need to set the Bundle Identifier in your Target Info to match the App ID in the provisioning profile.  That's step 6 under "Building your Application with Xcode for Distribution" in these instructions: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/distribution/index.action.  I don't think you need to do that for development builds, though.

Comment: I went to Keychain Access and I found that my certificate expired. Got the new one and problem resolved.

Comment: Downloading `safari_extension.cer` will do the job?

Answer (score 0):

Apple's steps to troubleshoot the issue are here: [How do I resolve the CodeSign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in the default keychain](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG41-HOW_DO_I_RESOLVE_THE_CODESIGN_ERROR__THE_IDENTITY__IPHONE_DEVELOPER__DOESN_T_MATCH_ANY_VALID__NON_EXPIRED_CERTIFICATE_PRIVATE_KEY_PAIR_IN_THE_DEFAULT_KEYCHAIN)

Answer (score -1):

- Just open a bash.
- Go into the ProjectName**.xcodeproj** directory
- And **remove every *.mode1v3 and *.pbxuser file**

Then start xcode again and you're lucky.

For my case it was like:

- cd iCodeBrowser/iCodeBrowser.xcodeproj/
- rm brandontrieb.*