# Build for archive doesn't work

Tags: xcode, app-store

I can click on Archive, but then Xcode returns to me:

> Code Sign error: the identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

I have also set well the company name and all this stuff. Any idea why it returns me the error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [code sign error : doesnt match key pair in default keychain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452969/code-sign-error-doesnt-match-key-pair-in-default-keychain)

Comment: The answer to this question has got to be all over the internet in a googolplex places.

Comment: I agree it's all over the place in a Googoplex places, but I don't think this is a dupe of the "doesn't match key pair" question as much as I think it's just a "how do I create an installable archive" question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create, download and install certificates and/or provisioning profiles for your project.

Go to Apple's ["iOS Provisioning Portal"](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action) and look at all the Help resources on the right side of the web page.

The instructions to do what you're looking for looks something like this:

[image: Apple's How To Videos]

Comment: Yes! That's it! I searched on google this error, but I didn't find the right answer. And that's it! Thank you!