# Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

Tags: iphone, xcode, code-signing

XCode is giving me the above error. This is my first experience with, what I'm assured is, the "easiest platform to write code with, ever".

The response in [Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108503/code-sign-error-the-identity-iphone-developer-doesnt-match-any-valid-certifi) of making sure the "Debug" and "Release" (which I assume means "Distribution") are the same did not help.

I don't see a program portal portion off http://developer.apple.com on signing in, as I should according to [Code signing error: Doesn't match key pair in default keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452969/code-sign-error-doesnt-match-key-pair-in-default-keychain).

I also found https://webbuilders.wordpress.com/2009/12/25/code-sign-errors-profile-doesnt-match-any-valid-certificateprivate-key-pair-in-the-default-keychain/ whose steps I followed and it still doesn't want to build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to a special new bottomless source of frustration! Coding for iOS is great—once you get the hang of it, Objective-C is a great language and UIKit has (for the most part) really well-built frameworks with clean, intuitive APIs. But using Xcode to get your code running on your device can be a miserable experience that tries your patience and sanity, presenting you with unintelligible, random errors for no apparent reason, even when the same thing worked yesterday. Believe it or not, provisioning (the process of signing your app with a developer key so that it's allowed to run on the device) isn't as bad as it used to be, because Automatic Device Provisioning takes care of a lot of the tedious setup bits now. See Technote 2250 for details:

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html

Also, you did pay the $99 for the iOS Developer Program, right? You can't get a developer profile and deploy to your iOS device without that.

Answer (score 0):

As stated ..i was trying to get a IPA file (for testflight.com) but without enroll int he developer program .... i got the same error.  You need a certificate installed after enrolling.